Complicated barrier options

We have the following contract consisting of barrier options:

If $S_t$ is above the barrier level $B$ during the contract duration, we receive $N\cdot \max (S_T-4.45,0), 4.45>B$ from the
bank, where $N$ - nominal value.
If $S_t$ droped below  level  $B$ during the contract duration, then if $S_T\ge4.65$ we will receive $N\cdot (S_T-4.65) $ from the bank, and otherwise we will pay the bank $N\cdot (4.65-S_T)$.



Derive the condition that the contract parameters must meet so that its value is zero at the time of conclusion, i.e. balance the current values ​​of the instruments that make up this contract.
Create a script that will determine the value of $B$ given the remaining parameters of this contract.

My understanding of the problem:
1. The contract consists of a down-in-call barrier option that expires if $S_t$ falls below $B$. Then the option is activated, consisting of a put issued to the bank and a call purchased by us for the same exercise price of $4.65$. Therefore, at the time of concluding the contract, the following condition should be met:
$$\text{call } K_1 = \text{call } K_2 - \text{put }K_2$$
However, I don't know how to discount barrier options and I haven't found any help in the literature. Could someone tell me what to use or send me some tips?
2. Our contract is an American-type barrier option. Therefore, the final payout depends on the relationship between $\min{S_t}$ and $B$ during the contract period. For this task, I have given market data, I can use the vanna-volga method to calculate various values, but I do not understand at all how I can determine the value of the $B$ barrier. I don't expect anyone to write the code for me, just explain to me what conditions I can use to arrive at the formula for $B$.

Based on my understanding of what you wrote, I would propose the following solutions:

The down-in-call barrier doesn't expire when $S_t < B$, it just activates and changes into the long call short put OR a long futures with strike $4.65$ as you have explained. If during the whole duration $S_t \geq B$, the it just stays as the call with strike $4.45$. But to answer the conditions that the down-in-call barrier expires with zero value:

If ($S_t > B$ for the whole duration AND $S_T < 4.45$) OR ($S_t < B$ for $\geq 1$ time in the whole duration AND $S_T = 4.65$).

I don't think this is an American-barrier? No where in what you wrote does it say that the option can be exercised at anytime, it sounds more like an European (correct me if I am wrong).

Also, "Create a script that will determine the value of $B$ given the remaining parameters of this contract." Are all the remaining parameters given? Can you specify them here?

That's right, the option can't be terminated at any time. I thought I could call this an American option in that we control the relationship between $S_t$ and $B$ over the life of the option, not just at time $T$.
I have table with ATM, 25RR, 10RR, 25BF, 10BF, FXspot, EUR rates, swap points for tenors ON, 1W, 2W, 1M, 2M, 3M, 6M, 9M, 1Y.

Is the price of the option provided? It seems unlikely to be able to determine $B$ unless you have that. If you have the price of the option, you could back out $B$ via Monte Carlo simulation (at least that is how I would do it).

I don't have price of the option explicite. But if I understand correctly, I have the market data to find the option price using methods such as black-scholes and vanna-volga. So let's assume I manage to price the option. Could you tell me what your idea would be to find barrier $B$?

That seems like a good idea. I would simulate the spot using GBM (you can find the formula online), then specify the parameters accordingly - you should keep everything else constant but vary the barrier level $B$ until you find that the Monte Carlo simulation produces the same price that you have with Black-Scholes/Vanna-Volga.
